# Flutter Searchable dropwn dropdown selected value returns always null

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

**Here is my Code**

```
SearchableDropdown.single(

isExpanded: true,
hint: 'Choose country',
value: countrySeleted,
selectedValueWidgetFn: (val) {
return Text(countrySeleted.name);
},
dialogBox: true,
items: countries.map((e) =>
DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(e.name)))
.toList(),
onChanged: (value) {

setState(() {
countrySeleted = value;
});
},
)
```

> **this value comes always null in on changed when the items are selected**

Flutter Searchable dropwn dropdown selected value returns always null

dependency: searchable_dropdown: ^1.1.3

Comment: Could you improve indentation and also show how you declare countrySelected (you missed a c by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"value" tag for "items" is missing thats why it is returning null. Providing value to items might solve this error.
Try following code:

```
                            SearchableDropdown.single(
                              isExpanded: true,
                              hint: 'Choose country',
                              value: countrySeleted,
                              selectedValueWidgetFn: (val) {
                                return Text(countrySeleted.name);
                              },
                              dialogBox: true,
                              items: countries.map((e) =>
                                  DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(e.name),
                                  value: e,)
                                    )
                                  .toList(),

                            onChanged: (value) {

                              setState(() {
                                countrySeleted = value;
                              });
                            },
                              )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the value was missing in the DropdownMenuItem item.